# Not receiving emails from Jira

Tags: jira

We're using Jira 3.6.5 for issue management.  We interact with it via a browser interface.

There are certain actions that are supposed to generate emails to a team member.  For example, if an issue is assigned to a particular team member, that team member is supposed to get an email from Jira.

Recently this has stopped working.  When I look in the Jira log files, I see messages like this when an email is supposed to get sent but doesn't:

2020-03-23 16:36:23,927 INFO [atlassian.jira.mail.MailThreadManagerImpl] Couldn't find Notification Instance record for issue 52824, so can't thread related email

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Mail Queue to see if there are stuck messages in it? You may need to flush the queue. I am not sure what is causing this error.

Comment: Yes.  There is nothing in the queue.